# Need regular expression that avoids substring

Tags: regex

I would like a regular expression to match an image format from a string(an url), but avoiding a concrete domain or directory.
For example:

"myImages/small/myImage.png"

"myImages/xxxx/myImage.png"

"myImages/large/myImage.png"

I would like a regexp to match any but not the 'large' one...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What you say "match an image format" what do you mean? You want to find out the extension of all files? You want to find the full content of all paths that end in specific extensions?

Comment: I only wanted to discard or to accept each image depending on its url.

Answer (score 3):

You want a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
myImages\/(?!large\/).+\.(?:png|jpg|gif|jpeg|svg)$
```

The above will match any path that ends with one of those file extensions, but that does not have the text "large/" following "myImages/".

*It's not very clear what your needs are, what output you want and what you can and cannot anchor against. If you edit your question to be more clear, you can get more-targeted information.*

Comment: Why are you escaping the first forward slash and not the second one?

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert I was assuming a language like JavaScript or Ruby where the regex can be delimited in a literal using forward slashes. Since I don't really know what the application is, I'll remove those.

Comment: It's not a problem, but I was just wondering why you were using a plain and escaped slash in a single regex

Comment: Many thanks, I just wanted to see a regexp with the negative expression. The application is in php.